# Combine the PK to A column in a table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table with four columns: `ID`, `animalid`, `calvdate`, `AnimalidLactNo`; `AnimalidLactNo` is concat between the PK(`ID`) and `animalid`.

I have tried the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE calvingdatecombined
(
    animalid varchar(80) ,
    calvDate varchar(15) NOT NUll,
    AnimalidLactNo AS CAST(ID AS VARCHAR) + animalid
);
```

My expected output

```
# ID, animalid, calvDate, AnimalidLactNo
```

My sample data output after running an insert statement should be:

```
1, TZNDJ02, 2016-06-18, 1-TZNDJ02
```

Comment: Depending on your MySQL server version, you can look at [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: I'd either use trigger or a separate view for this, as the column should be up-to-date at all times?

Comment: i am using mysql version  5.7.23 @maxim fedorov

Comment: I want to insert data from tables with data into this table, so i can not use a trigger

Comment: I think your question title needs better wording. The problem doesn't seem to be that PK can't be combined with another column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 5.7 with NDB Cluster 7.5.3 then you should have support for [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
CREATE TABLE calvingdatecombined (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    animalid VARCHAR(80),
    calvDate VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    AnimalidLactNo VARCHAR(100) AS CONCAT(CAST(ID AS CHAR(20)), '-', animalid),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

You may make this column `VIRTUAL`, which means it gets computed on the fly when you select, or `STORED`, in which case the value gets stored whenever you insert or update.

Note that even if you don't want to/can't use a generated column, you may still just select the concatenated expression, e.g.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    animalid,
    calvDate,
    CONCAT(CAST(ID AS CHAR(20)), '-', animalid) AS AnimalidLactNo
FROM calvingdatecombined;
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. Generated columns are only supported by NDB Cluster engines in MySQL 5.7; 8.0 and above do support it for InnoDB. But I think NDB cluster is not a very commonly used engine, and I doubt OP uses it.

Comment: I also doubt this, yet I recall using generated columns in MySQL before.

Comment: Could you add an example for virtual column as well?

Comment: @Nae They are `VIRTUAL` by default.  If you want to make them `STORED`, then just `AnimalidLactNo VARCHAR(100) AS ... STORED`.